# Count only dropdown cells google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a sheet where A column has 100 rows as dropdown menus, but a few rows have plain text. I would like to count only dropdown cells.

What's the second parameter we can use?

`=COUNTIF(A:A; "----")`

[Worksheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uCZ6wXeSZgYXGC9JsYYG0DEmlMMT0K2BBMkN2be3SlE/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are many possible values for the drop-down menu stored in the `Data` tab, try this in `C2`:

```
=SUM(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFNA(
      IF(
        MATCH($A$1:$A,Data!$A$1:$A,0)>0,1,0)
    ,0)
  )
)
```

This looks at all the values in column `A` and checks for a match in column `A` of the `Data` tab. If a match is found (`MATCH(...)>0`) we add `1` to the total. If a match is not found it will throw an "`N/A`" error, which we catch by adding 0 to the total.

I've updated the formula in [C4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uCZ6wXeSZgYXGC9JsYYG0DEmlMMT0K2BBMkN2be3SlE/edit#gid=0&range=C4) of your example sheet & as you can see it returns the expected result of 97.

Comment: But the plain texts are also different values.

Comment: can you elaborate on why you want to count how many are drop-down values?

Comment: Yes, you can review the Worksheet demo now. I have a long list and there is some plain text as labels. Like: March, April, May, etc...

Comment: Yep, I’ve taken a look at the example, thanks for including! Check out the formulas I’ve added in `B4` and `C4` as solutions.

Comment: Sorry, it does not make sense. Please renew the worksheet now, there is a lot of random value with dropdown.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks again for the added context. See new answer which takes into account that there are many possible options for the dropdown box.